# How to allow remote connection in MS SQL server management studio, on a port different then 1433?

Tags: sql-server, database, database-connection, remote-connection, management-studio-express

I was having credentials for this remote MS SQL database for quite a long time. The port for connection was 1433 and I was connected via "Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio".

After some time, my client changed the credentials and gave me the new ones. With these new credentials I can not establish a connection successfully and I got the following error:

[image: error]

I assume that the reason for this is the fact that in the new credentials, the port is different then the default 1433 port which "Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio" uses (they are using port 5555 now) and in the log screen I can not see a way to assign a port to which I want to connect:

[image: login panel]

The new credentials which I got from the client, I confirmed that are correct, since I'm able to use them and to establish a connection with a different software (HeidiSQL - where at the login screen I can specify a port), but I really need to use "Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio".

There are some things which I did, from the following **[link](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20Docs-v1.1.2/GUID-CF5C89EA-0918-4002-8391-80CBEDE0BB5E)**, but still not success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1:

In the Connect to Server dialog, use Server Name: `server,5555`.

Option 2:

Alternatively you can run up SQL Server Configuration Manager on your workstation and add a client alias:

- SQL Server Configuration Manager (local)

  - SQL Native Client (version) Configuration (32-bit)
  - Aliases

    - Alias Name: SomeFriendlyName
    - Server: servername,5555
    - Protocol: tcp
  - SQL Native Client (version) Configuration (64-bit)
  - Aliases

    - Alias Name: SomeFriendlyName
    - Server: servername,5555
    - Protocol: tcp

Then in the Connect to Server dialog you can use Server Name: SomeFriendlyName.

==

Also your error message mentioned the Named Pipes Provider, which is not the same thing as the TCP/IP provider. In the Native Client Configurations > Protocols you should check that "Shared Memory" and "Named Pipes" are set to disabled and that "TCP/IP" is set to enabled. Do this in both the 32-bit and 64-bit configurations.